# Django form doesn't get the value in clean method

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to write a clean method form one of my forms in `Django 1.5`.
The user has the ability to chose from a list of pre existing objects or inserting one by himself, but he have to do one of this two things (if he do both the `ModelChoiceField` has precedence in the relative view).

This is the incriminated form's part:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.all(), required=False, label='What subject this file is about?')
    subject1 = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Or insert your subject if you didn't find it in the menu")

    def clean_subject(self):
        subject = self.cleaned_data.get('subject')
        subject1 = self.cleaned_data.get('subject1')
        if not subject and not subject1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required.')
```

whitch is relative to this model:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 30, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

problem is: if the user let the `ModelChoiceField` empty and tries to insert a value in the `CharField` the form raises the error anyway (and of course it shouldn't).

I also tryed: `subject1 = self.cleaned_data.get('subject1', None)` but in this case the `subject1` value will always be `None` (so the problem it's basically the same).

I'm really going crazy trying to undestrand why.

Comment: Is the name attribute 'subject1' for that input in your HTML?  How are you instantiating the form?

Comment: I'm doing the fast way: `{ form.as_p } `.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `clean` method instead of `clean_<fieldname>` to validate fields that depend on each other ([Django clean() docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)).

```
class UploadFileForm(form.Form):
    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.all(), required=False)
    subject1 = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        subject = self.cleaned_data.get('subject')
        subject1 = self.cleaned_data.get('subject1')
        if not subject and not subject1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Subject field is required.')
        return self.cleaned_data
```